# Передача двумерного массива на сортировку

Tags: c, алгоритм, сортировка

Имеется двумерный массив 5*2. Надо сделать так, чтобы массив отсортировался в порядке возрастания по первому элементу каждой пары. По заданию для этого действия нужно обязательно использовать пирамидальную сортировку (сортировку кучей). На выводе меня ждал странный результат, в котором первый элемент одной пары мог поменяться со вторым элементом другой пары. Это совершенно не то.

Скорее всего я неправильно передаю массив в функцию или неправильно манипулирую с массивами в самих функциях, но я так и не понял как надо правильно.

Далее будет приведён код и некорректный вывод. Заранее спасибо!

[image: Вывод в консольном окне.]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Функция "просеивания" через кучу - формирование кучи
void siftDown(int *numbers, int root, int bottom)
{
    int maxChild; // индекс максимального потомка
    int done = 0; // флаг того, что куча сформирована
    // Пока не дошли до последнего ряда
    while ((root * 2 <= bottom) && (!done))
    {
        if (root * 2 == bottom)    // если мы в последнем ряду,
            maxChild = root * 2;    // запоминаем левый потомок
        // иначе запоминаем больший потомок из двух
        else if (numbers[root * 2] > numbers[root * 2 + 1])
            maxChild = root * 2;
        else
            maxChild = root * 2 + 1;
        // если элемент вершины меньше максимального потомка
        if (numbers[root] < numbers[maxChild])
        {
            int temp = numbers[root]; // меняем их местами
            numbers[root] = numbers[maxChild];
            numbers[maxChild] = temp;
            root = maxChild;
        }
        else // иначе
            done = 1; // пирамида сформирована
    }
}

// Функция сортировки на куче
void heapSort(int *numbers, int array_size)
{
    // Формируем нижний ряд пирамиды
    for (int i = (array_size / 2); i >= 0; i--)
        siftDown(numbers, i, array_size - 1);
    // Просеиваем через пирамиду остальные элементы
    for (int i = array_size - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int temp = numbers[0];
        numbers[0] = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = temp;
        siftDown(numbers, 0, i - 1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //объявление массива
    int a[5][2]=
    {
        {2,5},
        {3,6},
        {9,8},
        {7,4},
        {5,1}
    };

    //вывод элементов массива перед сортировкой
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    heapSort(a, 5); // вызов функции сортировки

    //вывод элементов массива после сортировки
    for (int j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<2; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Всё как-то не так.. В массиве десять элементов. Вы передаёте аргументом пять. `heapSort(a, 5);`

Comment: Да, я передаю пять, потому что мне требуется отсортировать не десять элементов по возрастанию, а пять пар элементов по возрастанию, опираясь на первый элемент каждой пары. Соответственно, я думаю, что мне для этого требуется пять элементов от каждой пары, а не десять элементов всего массива. Если не так, то поправьте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В начале массива, объявленного таким образом, лежат элементы `2,5,3,6,9`,и они, как видно из вывода, нормально сортируются. При минимальном изменении кода можно добиться желаемого, если внутри сортировки использовать индексы numbers, умноженные на 2, и при обмене ещё обменивать следующий элемент, например

```
  int temp = numbers[2*root]; // меняем их местами
  numbers[2*root] = numbers[2*maxChild];
  numbers[2*maxChild] = temp;
  temp = numbers[2*root+1]; // меняем их местами
  numbers[2*root+1] = numbers[2*maxChild+1];
  numbers[2*maxChild+1] = temp;
```

Но по уму функция сортировки должна принимать аргумент - двумерный массив.

Comment: Индексы я не умножал на 2, но вместо этого, как Вы рекомендовали, я передал в функцию аргумент в качестве двумерного массива. Ну и далее я засунул операцию передачу элемента в цикл, чтобы можно было передавать два элемента.
Спасибо большое Вам за совет!